# ASP.NET MVC 5 Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying to use route attributes in MVC 5. I created an empty MVC project in Visual Studio to experiment with and so far I can't get the routing to work. [I'm using this page as a reference.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) I have the latest assemblies and updated all NuGet packages to their latest versions.

Here's my code:

```
// RouteConfig.cs
namespace MvcApplication1
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            // Enables MVC attribute routing.
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            // The default route mapping. These are "out of the bag" defaults.
            routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
        }
    }
}

// TestControler.cs
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public ContentResult Output1()
        {
            return Content("Output 1");
        }

        [Route("Test/Output2")]
        public ContentResult Test2()
        {
            return Content("Output 2");
        }
    }
}


@* Index.cshtml *@
@Html.Action("Output1", "Test")
@Html.Action("Output2", "Test")
```

The Output1() method renders properly. However, when Output2() is rendered, I get the error "A public action method 'Output2' was not found on controller 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.TestController'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because @Html.Action will not actually use routing. With it you explicitly specify actions and controllers.
The routing will be used when someone for instance makes the `http://example.org/Test/Output2` request from a browser.

Comment: This is very bad news for my situation. In my project, I have some MVC routing which isn't being honored and I have to use relative URLs instead of Url.Action. This is problematic because I use ReSharper to check for all uses of a particular controller method in my views. With the relative Urls, I'm unable to find all uses of a particular controller method and I have to do a project-wide string search. I was hoping the route attributes would solve this problem, but it looks like they are more suited for Web API than MVC.

Comment: @Halcyon If you have your routing setup correctly, the Action() method will output the correct route, even if you use attributes.

Answer (score 8):

Your action is named `Test2` not `Output2`. Change the following

```
@Html.Action("Test2", "Test")
```

Comment: That is correct. I named it Test2 and would like the route attribute to intercept the call to "/test/output2" and use the Test2 method. In the examples on the blog post I linked to, they had route attributes that were named differently than the method names. I'd like to be able to do this.

Comment: You can name the routes anything you want, but the `Html.Action` method parameters are based on the actual method names in the controller.